# Bootstrap 3 tabs hover styling issue

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am having an issue "combining" these 2 hover styles to perform together, if anyone could take a look would be great.

http://jsfiddle.net/H8vUW/

I need these hovers:

```
.services-icon:hover {
color: #fff;
cursor: pointer;
}

.services-icon-holder:hover {
background: #272727;
cursor: pointer;
}
```

To activate when the user hovers over each tab name as well (design, eshop, social, etc)

Also I made it possible for the icon to turn white on hover of the circle by increasing the height and width of the icon, but this is a little janky to me, for example when you move your mouse over just the beginning of the circle the icon doesnt turn white!

Here is an example of the active and hover: http://aliensix.com/lightningbolt/example.jpg

Active would be with arrow, hover without arrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/magnus16/H8vUW/1/)**.

You have to trigger both css on holder's hover. When you hover over icon, this automatically triggers the parent's hover too.

```
.services-icon-holder:hover {
    background: #272727;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
}

.services-icon-holder:hover .services-icon {
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: Awesome learned something new! That works perfectly for that part! Do you have any idea about activating that hover when you hover over the text part as well (social, design, eshop, cloud, etc)

Comment: I am sorry. I didn't see your markup. That is not possible until you change your markup. The reason is, `<p>` lies after the holder and currently there is no previous sibling selector available in CSS. If some how, your icons were in the `<p>` or icons were after `<p>` it might be possible.

Comment: Ok let me see if I can adjust it!

Comment: I managed to adjust the html accordingly but im still not sure on the css if you can take a peek. http://jsfiddle.net/H8vUW/3/

Comment: It would be better if you include your text within the holder.

Comment: Would the <p> still be needed in that case?

Comment: Ah I managed to get it! <p> was not needed! Thanks so much dude!

Comment: Superb. Glad to be of help.

Comment: One more thing if you can take a really quick look, I've been trying been trying to center the whole tab element for like 3 days lol heres a screenshot if you have a sec http://aliensix.com/lightningbolt/screenshot.jpg thanks again Lokesh!

Comment: Ok that does work, but it's a little weird is there anyway to do it % based?

Comment: Well, yeah, set the width in %

Comment: Here is a [pen](http://codepen.io/magnus16/pen/GKcem) I created a while ago to explain vertical and horizontal alignment.

Comment: For some reason using % on the width just sets it back to where it was: http://jsfiddle.net/H8vUW/6/